# What is the inverse function of this x(t) here?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'm struggling to find the inverse here. I've tried using Wolfram Alpha, and it keeps having errors. I tried computing the integral of the inverse of v(t), but it doesn't give the inverse of x(t).

$$ x\left(t\right)=\int_{0}^{t}v_{x}\left(x\right)dx .$$
$$ v_{x}\left(t\right)=\frac{2}{c_{2}+C_{d}rt} $$

I don't know where to begin. I just need a good starting point, and I think I could figure it out. The derivative of the indefinite integral of v(t) is not the same as x(t), but if I add 3.19962 they become quite similar, but not exact.
$$ C_d=0.5,
r=1.1455, 
c_2=0.4
$$

How does the number 3.2 appear, and how can I calculate the inverse without using magic numbers?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^t\frac1{a+bx}dx=\ln\left|\frac{a+bt}a\right|.$

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Like how to apply that more specifically to the problem

Comment: Your function $x(t)$ is of this form. So you can compute it explicitely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143126/discussion-between-r3fl3ct-and-anne-bauval).

Comment: You are welcome.